# How to upgrade docker clightning

Tags: core-lightning

I tried to update clightning to the new version of 0.7 by

1. docker-compose stop
2. docker-compose rm clightning_bitcoin
3. docker-compose up

However, it is still version 0.63
Where do I set that it is upgrading to 0.7?

Would this change in docker-compose.yml be correct?

```
  clightning_bitcoin:
    image: elementsproject/lightningd
```

to

```
  clightning_bitcoin:
    image: elementsproject/lightningd:latest
```

Comment: I don't use docker but maybe the people from clightning forgot to update the docker build. I would cross post that question in their issue tracker

Comment: Yep, that's it, we didn't get around to update the images right away :-)